# Missing updated property when using the delta query to track changes on users in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to track changes in any property of any user but it is not working for all properties. Here is what I'm doing:

1. I query the list of users using that request:
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
2. I follow the link in `@odata.nextLink` then save the link in `@odata.deltaLink.`
3. I update the `displayName` property of a user in Office portal.
4. I follow the previously saved link. I can see the updated value of `displayName` among other basic properties of that user.

The problem is that if I do the same with the `department` property, the user is returned but the new `department` value is not included in the json.

In the documentation(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview), it is said:

> Updated instances are represented by their id with at least the
>   properties that have been updated, but additional properties may be
>   included.

which is not the case here.

I have also tested the `jobTitle` property which is not working at all, meaning that if I change its value, the delta link does not show any change at all. I suppose it is the same for many other properties..

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please give us client-request-id and timestamp when you executed delta query?

Comment: client-request-id: 2640c633-8954-4259-9e3f-b6f92c04493c
I can't find the timestamp in the header but the request was done at 14h53 eastern time

Comment: Any development about this?

Comment: I am unable to repro this. I changed jobtitle and DQ request did show the changed jobtitle value. would you please send exact response prior to change and after change as well.

Comment: also, MS graph DQ shows only predefined property in response and department is not part of that. so you are not able to see department value but user is returned by delta request since that user's department was changed.

Comment: also please let us know are you using any filters ($filter or $select) in original query.

Answer (score 1):

I am able also to reproduce this issue. And event I specify `select` to display the `department` property, it still doesn't show in the changing result.

Based on the test, it seems that this property doesn't including in the track changes. If you have any idea or feedback about this REST, you can submit it from this [link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: It seems like many properties are not working after all.. I have just tested `jobTitle` which is not working at all (no change is reported).